# How can I show the approximate version of the fourier inversion formula?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let f be $L^1(R) \cap C_0(R)$ and satisfies $|\hat{f}(\alpha)|\leq A\frac{1}{|\alpha|}$, for all non zero real $\alpha$, for some positive A.

Then, show that for any $x \in R$,

$f(x) = \lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R} \hat{f}(\alpha)e^{i\alpha x} d\alpha$

holds.

--

Similar to the proof of the inversion formula, I tried to show this by using poisson kernel, $H(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-|\alpha|}e^{i\alpha x}  d\alpha, H_\lambda (x) = \lambda H(\lambda x)$.

(*)$|f(x) - \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R} \hat{f}(\alpha)e^{i\alpha x} d\alpha|
\leq$ $|f(x) - H_\lambda * f(x)| + \frac{1}{2\pi}|\int_{\mathbb R-[-R,R]}\hat{f}(\alpha)e^{i\alpha x}d\alpha| + |\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R} (e^{-|\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}|}-1)\hat{f}(\alpha)e^{i\alpha x} d\alpha|  $.

$|\int_{\mathbb R-[-R,R]}\hat{f}(\alpha)e^{i\alpha x}d\alpha| \leq 2\int_{R}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}}\frac{
A}{\alpha}d\alpha \leq \frac{
2A}{R}\int_{R}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}}d\alpha \leq \frac{
2A}{R}\frac{
1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{R}{\lambda}} $

$|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-R}^{R} (e^{-|\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}|}-1)\hat{f}(\alpha)e^{i\alpha x} d\alpha| \leq (e^{-\frac{R}{\lambda}}-1)|\int_{-R}^{R}\hat{f}(\alpha)e^{i\alpha x} d\alpha|
\leq (e^{-\frac{R}{\lambda}}-1)\int_{-R}^{R}||f||_1 d\alpha = 2R||f||_1(e^{-\frac{R}{\lambda}}-1)
$

However, If i let $\lambda$ ->   $\infty$, (*) becomes 0 for every R, if i don't let R to infinity. I think there should be mistake or misunderstanding. How can I show the equality?